# 9DOF Razor and BLE Mate 2

Tags: java, android, razor, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

**I cant get my android device to connect to my accelerator with Bluetooth LE.**

I'm Trying to read the acceleration values from a Razor 9DOF sensor,

found here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10736.

using Bluetooth LE,

found here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13019

This is the code I am using:

This is how I search for Bluetooth LE devices.

```
public class BluetoothActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private final static String TAG = BluetoothActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

private MelodySmartDevice melodySmartDevice;

private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

private ListView bluetoothListView;

private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
private boolean mScanning;
private Handler mHandler;

protected String mDeviceAddress;
protected String mDeviceName;

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);
    mHandler = new Handler();

    melodySmartDevice = MelodySmartDevice.getInstance();
    melodySmartDevice.init(getApplicationContext());


    // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
    // selectively disable BLE-related features.
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }


    bluetoothListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bluetoothListView);

    mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
    bluetoothListView.setAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
    bluetoothListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            scanLeDevice(false);

            mDeviceAddress = viewHolder.deviceAddress.getText().toString();
            mDeviceName = viewHolder.deviceName.getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OperatingDataActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("deviceAddress", mDeviceAddress);
            i.putExtra("deviceName", mDeviceName);
            startActivity(i);



        }
    });

    //set to scan when view opened
    if (!mScanning) {
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_bluetooth, menu);
        if (!mScanning) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_scan:
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_stop:
                scanLeDevice(false);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    melodySmartDevice.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            mScanning = true;
            melodySmartDevice.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
         melodySmartDevice.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            mInflator = BluetoothActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if (!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);

                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();

            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

            return view;
        }
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }

}
```

Then I send the device name and address to this Activity to start reading the values.

```
public class OperatingDataActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

protected static final String TAG = OperatingDataActivity.class.getSimpleName();


private boolean mConnected = false;

private RazorAHRS razor;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

private TextView txtStroke;
private TextView connectButton;
private AlertDialog connectingDialog;
private String deviceAddress;
private String deviceName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_operating_data);

    setTextViews();
    setupBluetooth();

    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Button Pressed");
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);

            razor = new RazorAHRS(device, new RazorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnglesUpdate(float yaw, float pitch, float roll) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSensorsUpdate(float accX, float accY, float accZ, float magX, float magY, float magZ, float gyrX, float gyrY, float gyrZ) {
                    txtStroke.setText(accZ + "");
                }

                @Override
                public void onIOExceptionAndDisconnect(IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectAttempt(int attempt, int maxAttempts) {
                    Toast.makeText(OperatingDataActivity.this, "Connect attempt " + attempt + " of " + maxAttempts + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectOk() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectFail(Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Failed");
                }
            });


        }
    });

}

private void setupBluetooth() {
    //Bluetooth LE-------------------
    /* Get the instance of the bluetooth le Android library and initialize it */



    deviceAddress = getIntent().getStringExtra("deviceAddress");
    deviceName = getIntent().getStringExtra("deviceAddress");



    if (deviceAddress != null) {

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Html.fromHtml("Connected to <b>" + deviceName + "</b>."), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    //----------------------------------
}

private void setTextViews() {
    txtStroke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStroke2);
    connectButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectButton2);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_operating_data, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_email) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmailActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.transition.slide_in_right, R.transition.slide_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.action_info) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VibrationHelp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.transition.slide_in_right, R.transition.slide_out_left);
    } else if (id == R.id.action_bluetooth) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.transition.slide_in_right, R.transition.slide_out_left);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The RazorAHRS code is found here: http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/IMU/SF9DOF_AHRS.zip
I didn't have enough space to add it to my question.